# How to find out the architecture of OS installed and get only the value 32 or 64 in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, cmd.exe, wmic

How to find out the architecture of OS installed and get only the value 32 or 64 in Windows?

With `wmic os get osarchitecture` I get :

```
OSArchitecture
64-bit
```

I only want `32` or `64` without `OSArchitecture`.

Comment: Is using Powershell an acceptable option for your situation?

Comment: No, I am using simple commands in cmd, i was wondering perhaps there's an equivalent to "grep" or "cut" (Linux) in Windows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get ONLY the Drive Label using WMIC?](http://superuser.com/questions/886574/is-it-possible-to-get-only-the-drive-label-using-wmic)

Comment: @Aziz - Post solutions as answers, don't edit your question, to include the solution.

Comment: @Aziz Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: I did it @DavidPostill, I put the answer, but it doesn't appear!

Answer (score 2):

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=-" %a in ('wmic os get osarchitecture ^| find "bit"') do @echo %a
```

Comment: I know it's not exactly the same as the OP's solution but I just wanted to improve it a bit.